# how to maintain copyright in a python code

Tags: python, author

Does anyone know how to set author data in python?
for example:

```
"""
Created on Tue Jan 17 17:06:12 2023

@author: glecca
"""
```

and that no one can erase or change that, please

I used the `# ," ", ''` and then put the code but my data can be cleared

Comment: There's no way you can prevent someone from editing any part of the code, including the copyright notice.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to add a license to your repo, though I don't know how they're properly enforced. But yeah, anyone can change anything they like about your code